# Python, Basic Function Confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to python, so I'm very very confused about what is wrong with the function. Basically, I want to make a function that check if x is integer, if it is, then it should evaluate it as "positive" or "negative." If not, then I want it to return "not int" as a result.

Here are the function that I tried to fix back and forth for some time now.

```
def negativeIntAlert(x):

  if x != int(x):
     return "not int"
  else:
     if x >= 0:
      return "positive"
     else:
      return "negative"
```

I do not understand why it doesn't work like it should, because it gives me "not int" almost every time. I also have problems with Boolean type such as: 
     negativeIntAlert(True) and it gives me "positive" instead of "not int", anything I can do to make Boolean = "not int" in this particular function?

Comment: `bool` is subclass of int in Python2 (historical reasons). And you should precise what "doesn't work like it should" means.

Comment: hint: `int(True) == True == 1` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like

```
def negativeIntAlert(x):
   if not isinstance(x, int):
       return "not int"
   else:
       if x >= 0:
           return "positive"
       else:
           return "negative"
```

**Update**
You want to solve the bool problem, so use `type` instead

```
   if type(x) != int:
       return "not int"
```

Answer (score 2):

For historical reason Boolean are inherited from int, so `isinstance(True, int)` will give you `True`, from [PEP-0285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/):

> This PEP proposes the introduction of a new built-in type, bool,
>       with two constants, False and True.  The bool type would be a
>       straightforward subtype (in C) of the int type, and the values
>       False and True would behave like 0 and 1 in most respects (for
>       example, False==0 and True==1 would be true) except repr() and
>       str().  All built-in operations that conceptually return a Boolean
>       result will be changed to return False or True instead of 0 or 1;
>       for example, comparisons, the "not" operator, and predicates like
>       isinstance().

So this would be better:

```
def negativeIntAlert(x):
    if isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(x, bool):
        if x >= 0:
            return "positive"
        else:
            return "negative"
    else:       
        return "not int"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead using if condition

```
def negativeIntAlert(x):
    try:    
        x = int(x)

        if x >= 0:
            return "positive"
        else:
            return "negative"
    except:
        print ("it is no an int")
```

Comment: `int(4.0)` return 4 so, this will not solve this problem